# Flipper: Flipper Hermes debugger does not show

Tags: react-native, react-devtools, flipper, react-native-hermes, fbflipper

Flipper `Hermes debugger` does not show

I would like to ask how to make him display normally？

react-native：0.62.2 (Update from 0.61 to 0.62.2)

https://fbflipper.com/

https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes

error message:

```
Metro is connected but no Hermes apps were found.

Open a React Native screen with Hermes enabled to connect. Note: you may need to reload the app in order to reconnect the device to Metro.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an app with Hermes enabled currently running in an emulator? If your app is using JSC, it will not show up in this list. You can check which VM is being used from JavaScript with `typeof(HermesInternal)`. "object" means Hermes while "undefined" means JSC

Answer (score 4):

Following this in android/app/build.gradle file

```
project.ext.react = [
  entryFile: "index.js",
  enableHermes: true 
]
```

And this in proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep class com.facebook.hermes.unicode.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.jni.** { *; }
```

And

$ cd android && ./gradlew clean

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was showing screen mentioned at https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1520

I found out that it was happening due to company VPN. I disconnected the VPN whenever I had to debug and it worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the below config in android/app/gradle.properties worked for me.

```
 expo.jsEngine=hermes
```

And then cd android && ./gradlew clean

You can also verify if hermes is enabled by adding below snippet to App.js or any other .js file in react native.

```
 const isHermes = () => !!global.HermesInternal;
 console.log("Is Hermes enabled " + isHermes())
```